# Type error: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'e' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to build the project and would like to deploy it to vercel but getting some type errors.

The site runs fine in development (using yarn dev).

These are the two functions am using to close a modal without event propagation.

```
    //Closes the modal
    const exitModal = (e) => {
    closeModal(false)

    //this part stops the click from propagating
    if (!e) var e = window.event
    e.cancelBubble = true
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation()
   }

  const exitAndRefresh = (e) => {
    exitModal(e)
    window.location.reload()
  }
```

The JSX below with the onClick function:

```
              <button
                className="absolute z-10 top-0 right-0 mt-1 mr-2 p-2 rounded-lg text-white bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700"
                onClick={exitModal}
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
```

**Build Error:** (using yarn build)

```
Type error: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'e' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'Event'.

  91 |
  92 |     //this part stops the click from propagating
> 93 |     if (!e) var e = window.event
     |                 ^
  94 |     e.cancelBubble = true
  95 |     if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation()
  96 |   }
```

I tried doing this -

```
//Closes the modal
  const exitModal = (e: Event) => {
    closeModal(false)

    //this part stops the click from propagating
    if (!e) var e = window.event
    e.cancelBubble = true
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation()
  }

  const exitAndRefresh = (e: Event) => {
    exitModal(e)
    window.location.reload()
  }
```

But got this error instead:

```
Type error: Type '(e: Event) => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': cancelBubble, composed, returnValue, srcElement, and 7 more.

  158 |               <button
  159 |                 className="absolute z-10 top-0 right-0 mt-1 mr-2 p-2 rounded-lg text-white bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700"
> 160 |                 onClick={exitModal}
      |                 ^
  161 |               >
  162 |                 Cancel
  163 |               </button>
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

This segment is an outdated snippet that stops propagation (cross browser):

```js
    //this part stops the click from propagating
    if (!e) var e = window.event
    e.cancelBubble = true
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation()
```

Personally I don't think we should be supporting IE indirectly by including extra code for it...

But anyways you don't need a `var` there:

```
//  const exitModal = (e: Event) => {
//                      ^^^^^^^ don't forget to annotate
e ??= window.event!; // if e is not there set it to window.event
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.stopPropagation?.(); // if stopPropagation exists call it
```

The exclamation mark there is to tell TypeScript that window.event exists.

This code uses the newest features of JavaScript: nullish coalescing assignment and optional chaining with function calls.

Since you're using a build system implicitly with NextJS you can just use these and don't have to worry about older browsers.